# Dual Boot: Does data get deleted because the drive is partitioned?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi

I'm pretty bad at the whole computer literacy thing, but for the most part I can Google things pretty well. From what I've read, partitioning deallocates everything on the partition that is getting modified. However, I've also read on the Installer package that if it's installed alongside my current OS, I won't lose my stuff (I've got Windows 8, and UEFI kinda sucks, but I can get the try Ubuntu to work. It's just not a cursor based GUI, and it's a lot less pretty). Does Ubuntu Desktop identify and reallocate everything as it was? Because I gotta say, if it does, that's pretty rad. If not, while I've got backups, I don't want to reinstall software. I can just wait until I get a new laptop and use have the clean slate with a dual boot.

Thanks,

If this is on another thread, please point me in the right way. I've spent 40 minutes trekking through these forums.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate a separate partition for Ubuntu if you are planning to dual-boot with windows. If you choose so, make sure that you have moved all data from these partition(s) to some other partition because installing Ubuntu will format this partition and you will lose data if you put anything here. In addition, installing Ubuntu alongside windows like described above will not harm your data that is still in windows. There are a lot of information on Ubuntu-Windows dual boot. To start with look at the [official](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to resize partitions in such a way that data are not lost, although the amount of free space on the resized partition(s) will change. New partitions for Ubuntu can then be created in the space "vacated" by the resized partition(s). The Ubuntu installer can do this automatically or semi-automatically in some cases.

***BEWARE, THOUGH!*** There are numerous posts here from people who've mistakenly wiped out their Windows installations by accidentally selecting an option that allocates the entire disk to Ubuntu when they'd intended to have Ubuntu coexist alongside their existing Windows installation. I haven't thoroughly investigated these cases, so I don't know what *specific* mistake they're making or what *specific* bug might exist in the Ubuntu installer that creates this problem. It's best to make a backup of all your important data before installing Ubuntu, just in case you run into this problem. When you do your installation, be sure to follow a procedure that explicitly states your Windows installation will remain intact. Pay particular attention to any partitioning instructions and the option on the "Installation Type" screen. If you don't see the option your procedure specifies on this screen, *do not* shrug your shoulders and select something else at random, since that could be the mistake that costs you your Windows installation. Research what each of the options you see does before picking one. (The available options vary depending on your current configuration and boot mode.)